# @submit not trigger a method vue/quasar

Tags: vue.js, vuex, quasar

> NOTE: According to my code correct answer is in answers.
>
> BUG CAUSED: In the latest version of Quasar (1.2.4), q-btn components that are in the v-slot:after slot of a q-input component will no longer submit the q-form (even with type="submit" added).

Just want to know where i did mistake my `q-btn` are not triggering `sendMessage()` method.

```html
<template>
  <q-page class="flex column">

    <div class="q-pa-md column col justify-end">
      <q-chat-message
        v-for="message in messages"
        :key="message.text"
        :name="message.from"
        :text="[message.text]"
        :sent="message.from === 'me' ? true : false"
      />
    </div>

    <q-footer elevated class="bg-secondary">
      <q-toolbar>
        <q-form class="full-width" @submit="sendMessage">
          <q-input v-model="newMessage" bg-color="white" outlined rounded label="Message" dense>
            <template v-slot:after>
              <q-btn type="submit" icon="send" color="white" round dense flat />
            </template>
          </q-input>
        </q-form>
      </q-toolbar>
    </q-footer>

  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      newMessage: '',
      messages: [
        {
          text: 'Yo dude',
          from: 'me'
        },
        {
          text: 'Yo dude im them',
          from: 'them'
        },
        {
          text: 'Yo duqweqrfq',
          from: 'me'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendMessage() {
      console.log('a new message arrived');
      this.messages.push({
        text: this.newMessage,
        from: 'me'
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the submit button will not work in the template of `QInput`. You need to put the Submit button outside of the `QInput` or you can use the button click event.

```
<q-form class="full-width" @submit="sendMessage">
         <div class="row">
          <q-input v-model="newMessage" bg-color="white" outlined rounded label="Message" class="col-11" dense>
          </q-input>
          <q-btn type="submit" icon="send" color="primary" round dense flat class="col-1" />
         </div>
       </q-form>
```

or

```
<div>
    <q-input v-model="newMessage" bg-color="white" outlined rounded label="Message" dense>
        <template v-slot:after>
          <q-btn type="submit" icon="send" color="white" @click="sendMessage" round dense flat />
        </template>
      </q-input>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/eYmNqdg?editors=1010

> NOTE: In the latest version of Quasar (1.2.4), q-btn components that are in the v-slot:after slot of a q-input component will no longer submit the q-form (even with type="submit" added).

Answer (score 1):

Change button `type="submit"` on method click. Quasar has changed something in recent releases

```
<q-btn @click="sendMessage" icon="send" color="white" round dense flat />
```